# Getting a deferred call using $.when in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery AJAX call inside `$.when()` so I can perform other operations when I get a callback. But unfortunately I am not getting the callback from the method I am calling which makes a successful AJAX call. Following is the code ...

```
/****** Code which calls the function ******/

var pathString = "/Cities?state=" + whichState;

$.when(makeAJAXRequest(pathString)).done(function(data)
{
    alert(data);                  //Shows undefined

    //Other operations ..... 
}

/****** My function which makes the AJAX call ******/

function makeAJAXRequest(pathString)
{

$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        async:'false',
        cache:false,
        url:'./proxy.php',
        data:{path:pathString},         //Can put the query-string in the path. But if put in data attribute, it will work with both GET and POST
        dataType:'xml',
        success:function(data)
        {
    //alert(data);

    return data;
    },
    error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    alert("Error in AJAX request: " + textStatus + errorThrown);

    return ("Error in AJAX request: " + textStatus + errorThrown);
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're really not returning a deferred object in your makeAjaxRequest() method.

It should be something like this:

```
function makeAJAXRequest(pathString) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        async:'false',
        cache:false,
        url:'./proxy.php',
        data:{path:pathString}
        dataType:'xml',
        success:function(data) {
            // Deferred object success
            return deferred.resolve(data);
        },  
        error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error in AJAX request: " + textStatus + errorThrown);
            // Deferred object reject
            return deferred.reject("Error in AJAX request: " + textStatus + errorThrown);
        });
    return deferred.promise();
    }
```

Please take a closer look at the Deferred documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Works really well. Is a perfect solution with 'error' callback as well.

Answer (score 0):

In `makeAJAXRequest()`, you just need to return `$.ajax` which is a `jqXHR` object http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

```
function makeAJAXRequest(pathString) {
    return $.ajax({
    // ...
    });
}
```